# Type Mismatch in PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Tags: vba, excel

I want to copy the contents of two excel in one, and all goes well until I copy the contents of my second excel, because this overwrites what the first copy excel, done that :

These are my statements:

```
Dim wbOrigen1 As Workbook, _
    wbOrigen2 As Workbook, _
    wsDestino As Excel.Worksheet, _
    wsOrigen1 As Excel.Worksheet, _
    wsOrigen2 As Excel.Worksheet, _
    rngOrigen1 As Excel.Range, _
    rngDestino As Excel.Range, _
    rngDestino2 As Excel.Range, _
    rngOrigen2 As Excel.Range
```

Here is the problem

```
ThisWorkbook.Activate
Set rngDestino2 = wsDestino.Range(celdaDestino,Range(celdaDestino).End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0))
Range(celdaDestino).End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
wsOrigen2.Activate
rngOrigen2.Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Selection.Copy
ThisWorkbook.Activate

rngDestino2.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

But this does not work the same way. The problem seems to be with `rngDestino2`

```
?rngDestino2
Type Mismatch
?err.Description
Type Mismatch
```

How I can fix it?

Comment: a) Where ae you setting `wsDestino`? Is `celdaDestino` set to a cell (or range of cells) on the `wsDestino` worksheet? Your description of the problem is sufficient but the sample code is insufficient to see where the problem is. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Ok sorry, is my first day... xD  wsDestino setting is "Set wsDestino = Worksheets("procesos consolidado")"
  celdaDestino setting  is = " Const celdaDestino = "A1" "      the problem is with this line: Set rngDestino2 = wsDestino.Range(celdaDestino,Range(celdaDestino).End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0))   I need to find the last cell used , and copy the contents of the book(wsDestino) here,.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to avoid select, activate and selection in deference to direct addressing. The paste special, values can also be handled more efficiently by direct cell value transfer.

```
'make sure that the worksheet vars are set correctly
set wsOrigen2 = <other workbook>.Sheets("Sheet1")
set wsDestino = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

With wsOrigen2.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
    wsDestino.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp) _
      .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count) = .Cells.Value
End With

set wsDestino = nothing
set wsOrigen2 = nothing
```

If the workbooks are open and the worksheets are set correctly, that should be all that you really require.

See [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) for more methods on getting away from replying on select and activate.